# enable "start" button when Process exec close the window in java

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am new to JAVA, I have javax.swing.JFrame which contains two buttons which is "start tree" and "start test". When i click on "start tree" it calls a CreateTree.jar file through Process(); the code is below.

```
Process treeProcess = new Process(javaHome + "/bin/java -Xms8m -Xmx" + _maximumHeapSize + " -jar lib/CreateTree.jar"); 
treeProcess.setOutputFile(_tmpPath + File.separator + "TreeTool.log");
treeProcess.exec();
```

the TreeTool is a seperate .jar file which creates some tree structure. after creates the tree structure, the user will upload some neccessary files and he has to do "start test" from first frame.

Now the users request is to disable to "start tree" as soon as clicked the button and should load the different window. then the user closes the second window it has enable it back. Problem i am finding here is when i call the CreateTree.jar through exec(); I am unable to get the property first window so i cant enable it back.

Please help me how to enable it back.

Thanks

Comment: What has this got to do with SWT?

Comment: why do you call the jar like that? why not just call the entry point of the code through your code?

Comment: I agree @Stultuske but this was already developed by some developer. I have joined recently.

Comment: *"I agree @Stultuske but this was already developed by some developer."* So? That wouldn't stop me from calling a constructor of well documented code, or failing the 'well documented', the `main(String[])` method. Using `exec` to run it is like using a sledgehammer to crack an egg. It's overkill and provides less feedback or control.

Comment: @AndrewThompson it would crack the egg though ^_^